# Large white space in the check queues

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, mobile-web, top-bar

Recently, the mobile version has changed a bit. On the top right, a button has been added. When you click on it, the queues of checks appear. But half the space is just a white spot:

[image]

Comment: Use the responsive design instead. Scroll down to the footer, hit “full site”. From the [tag wiki for mobile-web](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/mobile-web/info): _“Since the new responsive design will eventually replace the mobile version, bugs and feature request are unlikely to be fixed/implemented.”_

Comment: @SebastianSimon I know there is a responsive design, but I didn't use it because I don't like it

Comment: I have a change in review.  Every other topbar dialog is full height so I didn't want to rock the boat, but it does look weird and was easy enough to fix.

Comment: @BrianNickel the bug has been fixed at the moment, so could you please put [status-completed]?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been fixed.

The review queue menu is the only mobile topbar icon that will have reduced height, but anyone who has the review queue privilege won't notice the difference because their other menus will already be full.